# What is the best way to mock ember services that use ember-ajax in ember-cli-storybook to post and fetch data?

Tags: ember.js, storybook

I'm using [Ember CLI Storybook](https://github.com/storybookjs/ember-cli-storybook) to create a story of a component than internally relies upon services that communicate to the internet, to fetch and post information to the backend. The way I'm doing that is using ember-ajax.

I see how to mock an ember model from this [section](https://github.com/storybookjs/ember-cli-storybook#working-with-store) but wondering if there is a workaround for ember ajax service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use mswjs.io for mocking remote requests. It uses a service worker so you can still use your network log as if you still used your real API.

I have an example repo here showing how to set it up: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-data-resources/

But I'll copy the code, in case I change something.

Now, in tests, you'd want something like this: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-data-resources/blob/main/tests/unit/find-record-test.ts#L17

```js
module('findRecord', function (hooks) {
  setupMockData(hooks);
```

But since you're using storybook, you'd instead want the contents of that function. (And without the setup/teardown hooks unique to tests)

https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-data-resources/blob/main/tests/unit/-mock-data.ts#L22

```js
import { rest, setupWorker } from 'msw';

let worker;

export async function setupMockData() {
    if (!worker) {
      worker = setupWorker();
      await worker.start();
      // artificial timeout "just in case" worker takes a bit to boot
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      worker.printHandlers();
    }

    let data = [
      { id: '1', type: 'blogs', attributes: { name: `name:1` } },
      { id: '2', type: 'blogs', attributes: { name: `name:2` } },
      { id: '3', type: 'blogs', attributes: { name: `name:3` } },
    ];

    worker.use(
      rest.get('/blogs', (req, res, ctx) => {
        let id = req.url.searchParams.get('q[id]');

        if (id) {
          let record = data.find((datum) => datum.id === id);

          return res(ctx.json({ data: record }));
        }

        return res(ctx.json({ data }));
      }),

      rest.get('/blogs/:id', (req, res, ctx) => {
        let { id } = req.params;

        let record = data.find((datum) => datum.id === id);

        if (record) {
          return res(ctx.json({ data: record }));
        }

        return res(
          ctx.status(404),
          ctx.json({ errors: [{ status: '404', detail: 'Blog not found' }] })
        );
      })
    );
}
```

Docs for msw: https://mswjs.io/